# Equivalence of multiplying matrix inequality constraint by inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, constraints

I'm trying to understand the conditions for which
$$ A x \leq b \Leftrightarrow x \leq A^{-1}b$$
is true.

Let's assume that $A$ is a non-singular, $x$,$b\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I have come across an optimization problem where this does not seem to hold, my matrix is positive definite, non symmetric, does not have any particular structure and the off-diagonal elements can have different signs.

I would like to understand what might be the conditions on the matrix A which are necessary for this to hold.

Comment: Would $A$ being an M-matrix be sufficient? Although as I said I'm looking for some kind of necessary condition, if there is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M-matrices do not work. E.g.
$$
\pmatrix{-1\\ 0}\le\pmatrix{2&-1\\ -1&1}^{-1}\pmatrix{0\\ 0}
\ \text{ but }\ \pmatrix{2&-1\\ -1&1}\pmatrix{-1\\ 0}\not\le\pmatrix{0\\ 0}.
$$
The implication $\forall (x,b),\,Ax\le b\Rightarrow x\le A^{-1}b$ is actually equivalent to $0\le A^{-1}$, while the implication $\forall (x,b),\, x\le A^{-1}b\Rightarrow Ax\le b$ is equivalent to $A\ge0$. Therefore you need a matrix $A$ such that both $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are nonnegative. The only M-matrices that satisfy this requirement are the positive diagonal matrices.

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly the necessary condition that I am seeking is that $A$ must be such that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are nonnegative, right? If so, thanks very much!

Comment: @tomato Yes, you read it correctly.